# how to make a binary file to start as a service

Tags: 20.04

I have downloaded and installed CMAK to manage a Apache Kafka server.

Installation requires the binaries to be downloaded to a folder and then to run:

```
bin/cmak
```

inside that folder.

This will bring cmak up manually when you run the command and will show you on the console the CMAK log.

I am connecting to the server with SSH and this way I need to keep the session open to have CMAK running. Is it possible somehow to have it run as a service? so that on server start it starts and I don't have to manually start it on request or to keep the SSH session open?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to create a systemd service. Create the file `/lib/systemd/system/cmak.service` with the following content:

```
[Unit]
Description=
After=network.target

[Service]
Type=simple
ExecStart=/bin/cmak

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

You can enable/start the service with `systemctl enable cmak.service ; systemctl start cmak.service`. This is just a very simple example and can/should be modified to suit your needs.

Along with the above, there are a few examples at the bottom of this documentation that will be helpful: https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.service.html

Comment: it works! very good starting point. Thank you very much for your help!